# How to put the log of a bash command in a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

There is `script-one.sh` with the following content:

```
sh script-two.sh
# I need a here a way to store the log generated by the script-two is a variable
```

`script-two.sh` logs in terminal the string 'hello'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `$( )` aka [*command substitution*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst), so :

```
x="$(sh script-two.sh)"
echo "$x"
```

As said in the comment by @Walter, *double quotes* are needed :

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

#### Edit :

If you need to catch standard output ([stdout](/questions/tagged/stdout)), then my command is OK.

If you need instead [stderr](/questions/tagged/stderr), then:

```
x="$(sh script-two.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null)"
```

Or if you want both, then :

```
x="$(sh script-two.sh 2>&1)"
```

Comment: Cristian: Do not forget the quotes around `$x`.

Comment: Added examples with the different streams STDERR & STDOUT

Comment: When assigning to a variable, the double quotes are not necessary though :)